# Count non-empty rows in related table for each row (day) in date table

Tags: dax

I have a fact table with fields such as State (created, open, closed), where each row has a date. This table is related to a date-table via "Date". I need to create a column in the date table that counts the number of state "Created" for each day; for example 5 were created the 2. of february, resulting in the number 5 in the column "Created" next to the date 2/2 in the date-table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Date table  and calculate a column
formula `Count = CALCULATE(COUNTA(State[created]))`

Below are the screenshot
 state table

[image]

date table with count

[image]